# jquery.visible is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show the validations notice and error messages in my page ..

In my layout 
i have

and in my helper
 def flash_notice

```
render(:partial => 'shared/notice', :object => flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
```

end

ANd in my partial

<%= javascript_tag "$('notification_message').visualEffect('SlideDown');" %>
<%=
  update_page_tag do |page|
    page.delay(4) do

```
  if page['notification_message'].visible
    page['notification_message'].visual_effect :slide_up
  end
end
```

end
%>

where page['notification_message'].visible is showing error while loading..
showign the error as
page['notification_message'].visible is not a function

I have loaded jquery 1.4.js
prototype
still then its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should use visible in a selectore like this:

$("div.selector:visible").something()

this wil give you all the div's with a class 'selector" that are visible.

I can't really figure out what you want tod do with this coden so I hope this is a relevant answer.

Comment: This answer's correct, unless OP was trying to use the addon 'jQuery Visible' library